# what type R value insulation for 960 sq.ft. garage

Tags: insulation

I need to insulate a brand new 960 sq.ft. garage, 30 feet deep and 32 feet wide. planning on putting a house furnace w/central air. How should I go about insulating it, what R values where? I live in St. Louis, Mo.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Insulation is a capital expense - it can reduce other capital expense (use a smaller furnace) and running expenses (ongoing heating/cooling costs.) As such, more insulation is always better if you can afford it, as a long-term investment. R50-60 in the roof and 30+ in the walls, though if you've gone and had the foundation done with no insulation that's going to put a crimp in operating costs and comfort (generally R10 or 2 inch foamboard at a minimum is recommended for foundation/slab insulation.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- if you're willing to use a vented over-roof, there is basically no limit in how far you can take the R-value of a roof...

Comment: True, but diminishing returns impact it - the garage door(s) and any windows or man-doors will become the dominant area of heat loss/gain as you get to decent levels of roof/wall insulation. An R100 roof makes little difference if there's, say, 200 square feet of R10 garage door and 30 square feet of R3 windows/doors. If the garage doors are uninsulated cheapies, they become dominant faster and need to be replaced with good ones (mine are R17 commercial-grade.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- true :) you'd want a superinsulated door in such a construction, that's for sure

Answer (score 1):

Code minimum is generally R-13 for insulation inside stud walls, or R-10 for  insulation outboard of masonry walls. More is always better. But this question is far too broad and subjective to be satisfactorily answered; it's like "how should I build a house?" You can insulate your new garage any way you want, limited by the building code and existing construction (Frame? Block? Something else?), and subject to correct installation for the method you choose.

Answer (score 1):

I still consider this too broad/vague and have voted to close.

It's basically an engineering optimization problem, and the parameters on that problem are up to you:

Are you content with code minimum insulation and high heating/cooling bills - most builders are, as they are never going to live there and pay the bills. Cheap to build, expensive to own.

Do you seek something better? How much better? What are you willing to spend? How much trouble are you willing to go to, and/or space/volume are you willing to give up? The best time to deal with insulation is the design phase, not "well, here's a freshly built uninsulated garage, now let's put some lipstick on this pig and enter it in a beauty contest!" - You've probably got 2x4 walls, a 2x4 truss ceiling with no heel at the edges (meaning very little room for insulation at the edges of the ceiling) and it's already roofed and sided so you can't add external sheathing insulation without ripping off the brand-new roof and siding. Are your garage doors insulated? How well? What do you have for windows, and what is their R or U value?

You can work from this situation to "as good as you care to afford" but you start with constraints that you'll have to work within, or around. You can make extra space for insulation in the walls by building a false wall inside the wall, or you can fill with batts or cellulose or spray-foam and then overlay foam sheets and finish with drywall (and long drywall screws.) You can make extra space for insulation at the corners by dropping the edges of the ceiling. It will all cost money, and it's all subject to a simple mathematical relationship based on understanding "what is R-value?"

In "English" (now mostly only USA) units, "R-value" is a measure of how many square feet one BTU can maintain a 1 degree Fahrenheit difference across. So 17 square feet of "R17" material need just as much heating or cooling as 1 square foot of R1 material for the same temperature differential. As does 50 square feet of R-50 material. Metric R-values as used by the rest of the world are square meters times degree kelvin per watt and are 5.678 times smaller, but work the same.

Your total building heating/cooling load is the sum of all the heatflows, and the heatflows are the various areas of various R-value construction, at your functional temperature differences. Some are hard/impossible to change - the very best available windows are R10, and that may not last as it depends on exotic gas fills that may leak out over time. Most modern double-pane windows are R3 to R4. Going from a typical "uninsulated" construction which is usually R1-ish for wood to R-10 cuts your heating cooling load (read that as "operating expense of the heating/cooling equipment") by a factor of 10, aside from doors and windows.

When fuel/electricity is cheap, not very much insulation looks fine. As they become more expensive, more insulation looks smarter. As you improve the insulation in areas where it's easy to add (such as most of the roof/ceiling) the areas where it's difficult to improve the insulation become a larger part of the overall heatflow, which makes spending more on insulating a large, fairly well insulated area economically unviable. Something like half the heatflow in my 2000 square foot building is out the 196 square feet of windows at my current insulation levels - with no ventilation.

The rate of ventilation (pounds of air to be heated or cooled to maintain a certain number of air changes per hour) is a large proportion of the heat use in a well insulated, tight (you, rather than random leakage, have control over the ventilation rate) building, and makes a heat recovery ventilator look like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Mo hasn't adopted a statewide code. Your county requires R-13 walls, R-30 ceilings, in a home.

Simple bat insulation should suffice, kraft face installed toward the living space.

There are adequate installation instructions on the insulation packs.

Comment: Poly vapor barriers are a bad idea anywhere there's a summer. They only make sense in very cold places like Canada and farther north.

Comment: I see there is quite the push against using poly now. Go figure. I retract the poly suggestion (and will edit my post reflecting that) until they change their minds again. Good catch, dirt.

Comment: And I retract my negative vote! :)

Answer (score 0):

R60 Sounds about  right for the ceiling in your part of the country. That is going to be around 14 inches or more depending on the type of insulation you use. So having the space is important. As far as the walls go you are just going to fill them. Foam and cellulose will be the best for this. Foam because it offers the best R value and Cellulose because it is most cost efficient and easiest to dense pack.